# Firebase Functions Error, "db.batch() is not a function"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been having an issue with Firebase functions where when I deploy this function and try to change a user image, I get an error in the firebase function logs that says "Error, db.batch is not a function".

```
exports.onUserImageChange  = functions
    .firestore.document('/users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change) => {
      console.log(change.before.data());
      console.log(change.after.data());
      if (change.before.data().imageUrl !== change.after.data().imageUrl) {
        console.log('image has changed');
        var batch = db.batch();
        return db
          .collection('screams')
          .where('userHandle', '==', change.before.data().handle)
          .get()
          .then((data) => {
            data.forEach((doc) => {
              const scream = db.doc(`/screams/${doc.id}`);
              batch.update(scream, { userImage: change.after.data().imageUrl });
            });
            return batch.commit();
          });
      } else return true;
});
```

This is my db export:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { admin, db};
```

Comment: How are you importing `db`?

Comment: Thank you for making me check this, I realized I was importing it incorrectly

Comment: if you found an answer, you may post it and accept it for the community reference

Answer (score -2):

I guess the issue is that you have either not imported db correctly or you might have forgotten to assign the db variable before calling it.